# java.net.ConnectException error when running yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm having an error when running yarn on a job. HDFS and Yarn both start up fine, jps shows everything normal, pseudo-distributed mode on HDFS works perfectly, and I have triple and quadruple checked my configuration files. Whenever I attempt to run Yarn, however, this happens:

`INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: java.net.ConnectException: Call From serverA/IPaddress to serverB:30170 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused, while invoking ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication over null after 6 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 44428ms.`

Yarn then attempts to connect over and over again until I forcefully quit the process. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Did you read the link in the error?

Comment: I did, and attempted to debug it using that. Nothing appeared to be out of the ordinary but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: What exact command are you using? `start-yarn`? Or something else? Can you share your `yarn-site.xml` from both serverA and serverB?

Answer (score 0):

Can you see yarn web ui?

How did you start hdfs and yarn?

You can try `./sbin/start-all.sh`